# How to correctly open a file in an Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bucket

I uploaded some videos on Amazon S3 bucket. Following the url of these objects some are watched only with particular titles, ex. I can't watch "I-watch-the-tv", but I watch "I-watch-at-the-tv-on-the-couch" or  "I-watch-the-tv_1", so,  are there any rules to respect for names?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't watch"? What are you trying to do and what is happening? How did you upload the files? Do they have metadata that describes the file type?

Comment: i've a website, and I'm trying to upload the videos on  Amazon s3 for watch them on this website, now 
through the url that amazon give me (https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/my-video.mp4) same videos work and don't work with different name. For example:
If same video are renamed
"watch-the-tv" does not work,
"watch_the_tv", it works,
 "watch-the-tv-on-the-couch" works.  So i asking if there are rules for rename an object. The name are unique, there aren't videos with same name

Comment: Do those filenames include the `.mp4` extension? How are the files being uploaded? They might be losing their S3 `Content-Type` metadata.

Answer (score 0):

See the [section](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html) titled Object Key Naming conventions for an explanation of AWS S3 naming conventions. Without any other information to go on, maybe your permissions are set incorrectly?